# jQuery / IIS7 / Classic ASP - "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed"

Tags: jquery, iis-7, jquery-post

I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium (IIS7) using Classic ASP (please don't ask). Using jQuery to POST some data

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: "widgets/post.html",
   type: "POST",
   data:nhs,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html( data );
   }
});
```

Standalone, where I open up the HTML page, it works. However when I run it on localhost I get the error (with help from Firebug) of

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) is being used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,

JJ

Comment: usualy this means that the POST is not allowed, probably only GET allowed on the page. Can it be that there is some restriction on the protocol for this page?

Comment: are you using VS2005 and/or URL rewriting?

Comment: I changed the HTML extension to ASP and it worked